# .htaccess only one RewriteRule is not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I have a problem with **only one** page on the RewriteRule htaccess:

the page http://www.snes-fr.net/staff.html is not working (404) but ALL other are.

**staff.php** is in the folder: http://www.snes-fr.net/pages/staff.php

**.htaccess** line: `RewriteRule ^staff\.html$ index.php?page=staff [L]`

but this link is not working: http://www.snes-fr.net/staff.html
this one is working: http://www.snes-fr.net/cgu.html

`RewriteRule ^cgu\.html$ index.php?page=cgu [L]`

The code which show the page

```
$page = @htmlspecialchars($_GET['page'], ENT_QUOTES);
    if(is_file('pages/'.$page.'.php'))
       {
       require('pages/'.$page.'.php');
       }
```

Do you have any clue? Thank you

**EDIT:** htaccess:

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_4
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.snes-fr.net/404.html
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks

SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 1
SetEnv MAGIC_QUOTES 0


RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} decerto\.fr [NC]
RedirectMatch seeother ^/dossier-super-nintendo_([0-9]+)_(.*)\.html$ http://www.snes-fr.net/tests.html 
#REECRITURE


RewriteRule ^staff\.html$ index.php?page=staff [L]
RewriteRule ^cgu\.html$ index.php?page=cgu [L]
RewriteRule ^contact\.html$ index.php?page=contact [L]
RewriteRule ^404\.html$ index.php?page=404 [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ index.php [L]
```

...

All I have are working RewriteRule after !

Comment: I tested this rewrite rule in a localhost server and it actually works. There is probably another part of your `.htaccess` messing up with it. Can you show us it entirely?

Comment: Besides Guilherme's comment: why are you using htmlspecialchars here? You should add a check `if(realpath('pages/'.$page.'.php') == 'pages/'.$page.'.php')` to reject path-traversal, ie make `index.php?page=../../some-other-php` impossible

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier to use one line of code for all pages?
Something like

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hehe, no because I use other RewriteRule, with other var !

Answer (score 0):

Your line is correct, the problem has to come from elsewhere in the htaccess.
Can you share the rest of the file please ?

However, be careful, you should not use htmlspecialchars for protect your require.
You can rather use the function basename : http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

Comment: Just added the htaccess ! And I tried to remove `RedirectMatch` and the staff line is working... But, I don't see my mistake ...

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because of `MultiViews`

As per [**Officla Manual**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html):

> `Using a 'MultiViews' search, where the server does an implicit filename pattern match and chooses from among the results.`

Try turning it off on top of your `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```